# Python Datetime Delta - 15 minutes?

Tags: python, datetime, cookies, bottle, timedelta

I'm using bottle framework, and I was trying to set a cookie which will expire in 15 minutes, but it never worked, and I found that the issue is with the expire time I set.

My problem is I cannot get the `datetime.timedelta()` to add 15 minutes to the current time. It works only if I provide the "days" keyword parameter and set it to value other than 0.

that is:

it works in this way :

```
expire_date = datetime.datetime.now()
expire_date = expire_date + datetime.timedelta(days=10, seconds=900)
response.set_cookie("MyCook", "CookieVal", expires=expire_date)
```

Following doesn't work (cookie not created nor updated):

```
expire_date = datetime.datetime.now()
expire_date = expire_date + datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=900)
response.set_cookie("MyCook", "CookieVal", expires=expire_date)
```

OR

```
expire_date = datetime.datetime.now()
expire_date = expire_date + datetime.timedelta(seconds=900)
response.set_cookie("MyCook", "CookieVal", expires=expire_date)
```

I read the documentation, but it's unclear how this exactly works.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

can somebody please help me to figure this out? thanks in advance.

Comment: seconds is supposed to work, where are you using `expire_date` , it could be an issue there?

Comment: I've updated the question with what u asked. Please check. thanks for the comment.

Comment: How are you testing?

Comment: Sounds strange, it should definitely be working. Can you try printing out the `expire_date` to see what's going on. Also, you can do `datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)`

Comment: If i run your code with `print(expire_date)` after each time `expire_date` is set I see it incremented with 15min. So your problem is not in the `timedelta`, but at another place.

Comment: I run it in my browser and see if the cookies are set. Still not working. using minutes didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you live west of Greenwich?

The `set_cookie` function from bottle expects UTC datetime objects to convert them to string, so your timezone is not taken into account:

See https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L1729 :

```
value = value.timetuple()
....
value = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", value)
```

In other words, if you set an expiry date at 11:00am, that will be 11am GMT. That's 3:00am in Costa Rica, for instance.

Adding one or more days (or even a couple hours) to the expire date solves your problem because the `expire_date` value becomes greater than the current GMT time.

The right way to fix this problem is to use the current GMT time instead of your local current time:

```
expire_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```